# can someone tell whats wrong with my tree function

Tags: c

I have a tree where I need to to write a function that in each even root layer it must contain an even value and in each odd root layer it must contain and odd value also the odd values from the left must be 3 power the value (value^3) the odd value from the right odd value and the even value from the right should be bigger than the left even value if the statements were right then the function should return 1 if not then it return 0;

there will be a picture of what I meant below the code.

Here is my code:

> ```
>     typedef struct node
>     {
>         int value;
>         struct node *left;
>         struct node *right;
>     } node;
>      
> int main()
> {
>     node *root;
>     int even_odd=0;
>     printf("create a tree:\n");
>     root=create();/*the function to get the user input*/
>     i=0;
>     even_odd=evenodd(root,0);
>    
>    if ( even_odd)
>     {
>         printf("the tree is  an amazing tree\n");
>     }
>    
>     return 0;
> }
>
>     int evenodd(node *root, int n)
>     {
>          int check1=0,check2=0,counter=0,true1=0,true2=0;
>          if(root == NULL)
>          {
>              return 0;
>          }
>          else if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
>          {
>              return 0;
>          }
>          else
>          {
>              if (root->right != NULL && root->right && root->left)
>              {
>                  counter++;
>                  check1=evenodd(root->left,root->value);
>                  check2=evenodd(root->right,root->value);
>                  if (counter % 2 == 0)
>                  {
>                      if ((check2 %2==0 && check1%2==0) && check2>check1)
>                      {
>                          true1=1;
>                      }
>                  }
>                  else if (counter %2 != 0)
>                  {
>                      if ((check2 %2!=0 && check1%2!=0) && pow(check2,3) > check1)
>                      {
>                          true2=1;
>                      }
>                  }
>                  return (true1 && true2); /*the function returns 1*/
>              }
>          }
>      }
> ```

[image: tree]

Comment: Is something wrong with your code? Does it not work? If so, how exactly does it not work? You don't give any indication of what your problem is.

Comment: I really don't understand your evenodd function `(counter % 2 == 0)` will always be false.
`n` is not used etc.

Comment: @AndyLester in the main when the statement is right it should print something out like the tree is evenodd tree, but it doesn't at all,

Comment: @Ôrel How could i make it true ?

Comment: Your code will be *much* simpler if you simply `return 0;` any time you find a violation and have a `return 1;` at the end of the function. It will fix a logic error you have and avoid the need for special cases.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz but what's inside the statements worrying me it doesn't work

Comment: use a debugger with a paper sheet and a pen to check with basic case what happen vs what you want

Comment: @kitsune Why `&& root->right` in `root->right != NULL && root->right && root->left`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thats what came to my mind :(